# Crashing SQLite when comparing in query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a very simple SQLite query:

```
SELECT t1.[attribute] FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.[attribute] IN (SELECT distinct t2.[attribute] FROM Table1 t2 WHERE t1.[attribute] = t2.[attribute])
```

This query is crashing, in the "WHERE t1.[attribute] = t2.[attribute]" section. Regardless of this query having sense or not, why is it crashing?

Comment: This query as you posted it is syntactically valid, so the problem is somewhere else. Post the full error message.

Comment: I cannot get any error message, the program crashes completely.

Comment: There must be an error log. How do you know that the problem is the WHERE clause?

Comment: I am running the SQLiteDatabaseBrowserPortable program. If I try that query with another condition on the WHERE  part, it runs fine. Otherwise it crashes and i must kill the program

Comment: If you mean DB Browser for SQLite Portable this is a GUI for managing SQLite databases. If it crashes then this is a bug of the program.

Comment: Thank you, I just found the mistake. I was using an old version of the program. Updating to the latest release fixed the issue